# Spring boot - Java class version mismatch

Tags: java, version

I created demo application of Spring boot, and now try to run generated jar file, but I get the following error

> C:\Users\User\Downloads\demo\target>java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> com/example/demo/DemoApplication has been compiled by a more recent
> version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of
> the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

My Jre version is 1.8.0_271, java was configure in pom.xml to be 11. jdk version is 14.0.1. I tried to change java version in pom to 8, but then some 11 version related functionality doesn't work. How can this mismatch be resolved?

Comment: You cannot use newer Java features on older JREs. If you want to use Java 11 features you need a version 11 JRE.

Comment: How can I download 11 JRE?

Comment: Have a look at https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Comment: @dpr your link worked. I downloaded 11 version and run from this directory, now the error is gone. one question, how to make IntelliJ terminal run this particular java.exe from AdoptOpenJDK folder? so that I dont type the entire path to the exe file every time. Now when i just type java -jar filename, the problem of mismatch still persists

Comment: Should be somewhere the project settings. Just search for JDK or JRE and you'll probably find the right place

Comment: after restarting computer it worked, before that installer change JAVA_HOME environment variable to the new directory of installation.